# Como puedo mostrar en orden los datos mostrados desde mi base de datos en FireStore según fueron ingresados

Tags: flutter, dart

Tengo un formulario de síntomas en donde el usuario los ingresa y con esto obtiene la fecha en que se ingreso y luego tengo una ventana donde muestro los síntomas  que se ingresaron pero me los muestra desordenados.

Los datos los almaceno en FireStore en donde el usuario los ingresa en otro formulario.

```
class _readDataState extends State<readData> {
   final Stream<QuerySnapshot> users = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('users').snapshots();
   @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Sintomas'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 57, 137),
        elevation: 0.0,
        ),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Column(
              children: [
              Container(
                  height: 730,
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 5),
                  child: StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                    stream: users,
                    builder: (
                    BuildContext context,
                    AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot,
                  ) {if (snapshot.hasError) {
                       return Text('Algo salio mal');
                     }
                     if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Text('Cargando');
                     }
                     final data = snapshot.requireData;
                           return ListView.builder(
                                itemCount: data.size,
                                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                                   return Card( //Aca es donde muestro los datos almacenados en la base de datos
                                   child: Column(
                                   mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                   children: <Widget>[
                                      Text('Síntomas'),
                                      Text('${data.docs[index]['Fecha ingreso sintoma']}'),
                                      Text('''
                                 Fatiga: ${data.docs[index]['Fatiga']}
                                 Miccion: ${data.docs[index]['Miccion']}
                                 Flujo Vaginal: ${data.docs[index]['Flujo Vaginal']}
                                 Estreñimiento:  ${data.docs[index]['Estreñimiento']}
                                 Acidez Gastrica: ${data.docs[index]['Acidez Gastrica']}
                                 Sangrado Nasal: ${data.docs[index]['Sangrado Nasal']}
                                 Sangrado de encias: ${data.docs[index]['Sangrado de encias']}
                                 Hinchazon: ${data.docs[index]['Hinchazon']}
                                 Problemas respiratarios: ${data.docs[index]['Problemas respiratarios']}
```

Así es como me los muestra actualmente.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hay dos formas.

Puedes ordenar los datos una vez los hayas obtenidos o antes de obtenerlo, en la misma base de datos.

Para ordenarlos una vez obtenidos, tendrás que usar el método `.sort()` de las listas. A dicho método le puedes pasar una función que recibirá dos elementos a comparar dentro de la lista.

Creo que en tu caso, podría ser algo como:

```dart
data.docs.sort((doc1, doc2) {
// Comparar ambos documentos por fecha.
})
```

La otra forma es hacer una petición a la base de datos y pedir explícitamente, que los datos vengan ordenados. [Documentación Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/order-limit-data)

Por ejemplo, algo así:

```dart
final citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.orderBy("name").limit(3);
```

o así, para ordenar inversamente:

```dart
final citiesRef = db.collection("cities");
citiesRef.orderBy("name", descending: true).limit(3);
```